# Проверка метода запроса в Middleware

Tags: laravel

Пытаюсь сверить метод запроса который прописан в роуте с тем что пришел. Написал Middleware, в котором получаю метод пришедшего запроса `$request->method()`, как я могу получить метод который прописан в роуте?

Comment: Если в маршруте указан метод (например `post`), то запрос с другим методом по этому маршруту не будет передан в цепочку middlewares и соответсвенно контроллер. Так что это бессмысленное занятие.

Comment: @МаксимК, А как мне тогда проверить метод и вернуть пользователю ответ с ошибкой в виде json?

Comment: если есть `put` маршрут `/posts/5/set-suctom` и по такому пути больше нет маршрутов с другим методом, то отправив запрос по этому пути с методом `post`, laravel выдаст ответ `The %s method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: %s.` c кодом 405. Иначе код ответа будет 404